# Discord.JS - Edit existing embed field without creating a separate one

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to edit an already existing embed with a message that is sent buy a member.

The current code I have adds a separate embed field each time but I am trying to get it so that the value is added to an already existing field within an embed that has already been sent.

Code:

```
if (msgParams[0] == "!cb")
{

message.delete()

const message1 = message.content.slice(3)
let channel1 = message.channel.guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name.toLowerCase() === `balancing-sheet`)

const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor(0xffdb03)
.setDescription("<@" + message.author.id + "> is working on the " + message1)

channel1.send(embed1).then(sentMessage => {
            sentMessage.react("✅").then(() => {
                const filter = (reaction, user) => {

                   
                    return true;
                }

                const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector(filter);
                collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user, message) => {
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅'){

                      if (user.bot) return; 

                      sentMessage.delete()
                         
                        const suggestionData = await channel1.messages.fetch("885108855221125121"); // This is a pre existing embed that has been sent
                        const suggestionEmbed = suggestionData.embeds[0];


                        suggestionEmbed.addFields({name: "Cars Completed", value: message1, inline: true})
                        suggestionData.edit(suggestionEmbed);
                   
                    }                            
        })
    })
})

}
```

When the commands `!cb test1` and `!cb test2` are made, this is the outcome:

https://i.gyazo.com/f4cd3f171934e29b8e6786319ca9dc83.png (Cannot post image due to rep)

I am trying to change this so that `test2` appears under the same field as `test1`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may easily do so by saving your inputs to an array and further adding it as your field values after all values are taken up you may add them together

```js
const messages = [];
// initialize your array then listen for message event 
client.on("message" async ( message ) => {
if(message.author.bot) return 
const message1 = message.content.slice(3)
// send your embed 
const y = new MessageEmbed().setTitle(`Working on cars`)
const x = await message.channel.send(y)
messages.push(message1) // add your message content to array 
if(messages.length > 1) {
x.edit(embed.fields[0] = ({ name: `Completed Cars`, value : messages.join(`\n`)}); // each time a message is sent this would push the message to the array and join it with \n entity which represents a line break 
} else {
x.edit(embed.addField(`Completed Cars`, messages[0]));
}
})
```

Comment: I understand that I can set inline to `true` or `false` but this still doesn't add the `test` values under the same field.
Example below:

https://i.gyazo.com/913f20f5a102fec1e76368b44cf62cbc.png

Comment: This is the outcome I am trying to achieve:

https://i.gyazo.com/befe046d035e6316be017faa7cf07f28.png

Comment: This doesn't work with the current code I have + the collector.

Comment: Simply does not work does not explain anything about it, please show me your error

Comment: There is no error, it does the same thing as before. Adds a completely new field.

Comment: My bad I'll fix the field part real quick

Comment: Alright it should work now please check and give me a feedback

Comment: Appreciate the help but this still adds an extra field.